# Where is the "pre-launch" of Run/Debug configurations in Intellij saved?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, gruntjs

I tried to find where Intellij saves the job descriptions created in the "Before Launch" part, in the Run/Debug configurations popup cf. below
[image: Run/Debug Configurations popup of a project in Intellij]

You can see that I already added a Grunt job as "Before Launch" in this project. Now I would like to find where Intellij saves the description of this job in its xml configuration files (*.iws, *.ipr, *.iml). 
For now, I already found a line in my .iws file :

```
<method>
    <option name="ToolBeforeRunTask" enabled="true" actionId="Tool_Node_Grunt" />
</method>
```

It's just the line to enable or not this "Before Launch", but where is the parameter's job itself ?

The final goal will be to generate the Intellij configuration from gradle.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the full story, but won't it be easier to create a separate Gradle task with all necessary actions, and then simply launch it from Intellij? e.g. there is a Grunt plugin for Gradle https://github.com/srs/gradle-grunt-plugin

Comment: Indeed, run the project (and the before launches) through gradle should be more the simpler and cleaner solution in theory. But in practice Gradle is too slow for the development mode :)

Answer (score 0):

Pre-launch steps are generally stored in `main.iws`. For an “external tool”, however, your `main.iws` only contains a reference to something that is otherwise literally external to your specific configuration. Once an external tool is created, it is available to all other run configurations and templates.

IntelliJ stores the definitions of external tools as XML in `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2018.2/tools/External Tools.xml` (you might need to adjust `IntelliJIdea2018.2` to match your version).